# I need to open a file that was attached using "input type="file""

Tags: html, angularjs

This is the simple html code that i have

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="file" id="myFile"/>
</div>
```

Im using AngularJS and eventually i want to have the ability to add multiple files but right now i would like for the user to be able to open the file and verify if the correct file was uploaded.
Can i get the URL of said file?

EDIT: The files i want to upload are pdf's

Comment: Not really an answer, but have you looked at https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload? It allows you to bind to a file using `ng-model` as you normally would and gives you lots of file functionality, along with the ability to preview the file before uploading. It also supports multiple files out of the box.

Comment: Images or other files

Comment: @HiteshKansagara just pdf's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was posted in a comment in this question i ended up using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload